# Solr query to find one letter without other letter around

Tags: solr, lucene

I have documents in my solr already indexed. I want to find Producer and model in tire.
I have file with producer and model like this:

```
Nokian;WR G2 SUV
Nokian;WR SUV
Nokian;V
```

Query:

```
((productname:"NOKIAN" OR producer:"NOKIAN") AND (productname:"V" OR description:"V" OR referencenumber:"V"))
```

But it found for example this:

```
"2X NOKIAN 215/55 R17 94V LINE (3)"
```

Because in this product speed index is `V` and here model is `Line`. My algorithm take this product for `Nokian;V` not for `Nokian;Line`.

How to ask solr to gives me only this product where this `V` don't have any other letters around?

```
LETNIE 225/45/17 94V NOKIAN V  FINLAND - PŁOTY
```

This found beautiful. Its `Nokian;V`.

Comment: The data you posted looks like some raw, semicolon delimited data. Can you post a sample document from Solr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in such a way that sorted out brand,model Dictionary. I used my own comparer.

```
    public class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    int IComparer<string>.Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == y)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (x.Contains(y))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

All model that have `V` or `H` now are on the end of Dcitionary. It's works very well. Because first solr searched `Nokian;Line` and this product where found add to other list `alreadyFound` and skip this product where found model.  Thanks all for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question you need to put MUST quantifier before each boolean clause. So query will look like:

```
(
  +(productname:"NOKIAN" OR producer:"NOKIAN") AND
  +(productname:"V" OR description:"V" OR referencenumber:"V")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `productname` field is of type `text` it has the [WordDelimiterFilter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#line-541) in the analysis chain.  One of the default behaviors of this filter is to split terms on letter-number boundaries causing:

```
2X NOKIAN 215/55 R17 94V LINE (3)
```

to generate the following tokens:

```
2 X NOKIAN 215 55 R 17 94 V LINE 3
```

(which matches the "V" in your query).

---

You can always run `debug=results` to get an explanation for why something matches.  I think in this particular case, you might construct another field type for your `productname` field that analyzes your model string less aggressively.